# Why does Firefox 59 ignore my syspref.js?

Tags: 16.04, firefox

Recently, my `/etc/firefox/syspref.js` stopped being applied.
Unlike on Windows, where configuration errors results in

```
Failed to read the configuration file. Please contact your system administrator.
```

on my Ubuntu machines, firefox just silently ignores my settings.
Launching with the `-jsconsole` switch reveals

```
** Preference parsing error (line 1) = non-matching string **
```

I did not make any changes to my `/etc/firefox/syspref.js` file. It did work in Firefox 58 and stopped working with [the first Firefox 59 version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/59.0+build5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1). My file contains

```
// first line is ignored
lockPref("browser.startup.homepage", "https://example.org/");
```

**What can i do to**

1. **temporarily mitigate the problem: Make firefox read my config again?**
2. **permanently solve the problem: Prevent firefox from starting with invalid configuration when it encounters syntax errors in my system-wide config?**

Comment: See also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1426438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions, it seems that Mozilla changed the managed preferences again. My syspref.js is ignored in version 98. Now, you have to use the [JSON policies](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates)

Create a file `/etc/firefox/policies/policies.json` with some named setting described in the linked GitHub repo, or the original setting name under the a `Preferences` key:

```json
{
  "policies": {
    "Homepage": {
      "URL": "https://example.org/",
      "Locked": true,
      "StartPage": "homepage-locked"
    },
    "Preferences": {
      "browser.policies.loglevel": {
        "Value": "debug",
        "Status": "locked"
      },
      "browser.tabs.warnOnClose": {
        "Value": false,
        "Status": "default"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The application of this way of configuring Firefox can be reviewed in the about:policies page.

Comment: It still works for me. Maybe yours is a separate issue, not related to the syntax of the file, but your method of installation? I heard [Canonical gave up on compiling proper deb packages](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/feature-freeze-exception-seeding-the-official-firefox-snap-in-ubuntu-desktop/24210)..

Comment: I'm using the deb package from the Linux Mint repository. I haven't modified my syspref.js; it just stopped working after the upgrade to the newest version.

Answer (score 4):

I found out that you now have to use `pref("...","...",locked);` instead of `lockPref("...","...");`.

Example `syspref.js` (working in Firefox 61 on Linux Mint):

```
pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://...", locked);
pref("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "http://...", locked);
pref("network.proxy.type", 2, locked);
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed my problems. There is a lot of outdated info out there on the web including it seems mozilla's own docs..?!? I needed to set the default language and preferably lock it. The usual user_pref() or lockPref() / lock_pref() commands weren't working anymore. I ended up using the following which worked :
 

pref("intl.accept_languages", "en-au,en-gb,en", locked);

pref("intl.locale.requested", "en-gb");