# How to set system wide Preferences for Firefox 122 on 22.04

Tags: 22.04, firefox

I have looked a few options to set default homepage options for all users.  the options below added to `/etc/firefox/prefs.js` and `/usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/prefs.js`. Nothing seems to work and there isn't clear documentation that covers the latest deb version pushed out through Firefox's apt repo (non-snap version). I got the impression some release notes these config files are no longer used, which tallies with the fact they don't seem to change anything.

```
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "https://www.test.ac.uk");
user_pref("startup.homepage_override_url", "https://www.test.ac.uk");
user_pref("startup.homepage_welcome_url", "https://www.test.ac.uk");
```

Because of the odd method Firefox generates pref files, I'm having to resort to a fairly hacky methods to push lines of config into a given users config files: `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default-release/prefs.js`. This isn't ideal as I want to override other options to stop the Firefox welcome page as these are shared machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong file and [the wrong function](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061955/1004020). You want to open `/etc/firefox/syspref.js` and append the your lines fixed to become this:

```javascript
pref("browser.startup.homepage", "https://www.test.ac.uk", locked);
pref("startup.homepage_override_url", "https://www.test.ac.uk", locked);
pref("startup.homepage_welcome_url", "https://www.test.ac.uk", locked);
```

It's not named the same as the `prefs.js` in your Firefox profile. Also, `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/syspref.js` should be a symlink to `/etc/firefox/syspref.js` , and `/usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/prefs.js` shouldn't exist .

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I was really struggling to find proper documentation for this.